# How to read the VAO from the GLSL shader, or pass an Array of indefinite size to the shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glad

I partially managed to implement rendering by individual indexes - by loading the indexes into VAO, setting their layout, and passing them using glDrawArrays

but now another problem - for test i created arrays in shader itself -

`

```
#version 330 core

// Positions/Coordinates
layout (location = 0) in int V_Indices;
// Colors
layout (location = 1) in int T_Indices;
// Texture Coordinates
layout (location = 2) in int N_Indices;

 
 


vec3 Vertices[8] = vec3[8]( 
vec3(- 1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000),
vec3(-1.000000,  1.000000, 1.000000 ),
vec3(-1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000),
vec3(-1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000),
vec3( 1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000),
vec3( 1.000000,  1.000000, 1.000000),
vec3( 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000),
vec3( 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000));
//
vec2 Texcoords[] = vec2[22](

    vec2( 0.333333, 0.333333),
    vec2( 0.666667, 0.000000),
    vec2( 0.666667, 0.333333),
    vec2( 0.000000, 0.666667),
    vec2( 0.333333, 0.333333),
    vec2( 0.333333, 0.666667),
    vec2( 0.000000, 0.333333),
    vec2( 0.333333, 0.000000),
    vec2( 0.333333, 0.333333),
    vec2( 0.666667, 0.666667),
    vec2( 0.333333, 0.666667),
    vec2( 0.666667, 0.333333),
    vec2( 1.000000, 0.000000),
    vec2( 1.000000, 0.333333),
    vec2( 0.333333, 1.000000),
    vec2( 0.000000, 0.666667),
    vec2( 0.333333, 0.666667),
    vec2( 0.333333, 0.000000),
    vec2( 0.000000, 0.000000),
    vec2( 0.666667, 0.333333),
    vec2( 0.666667, 0.000000),
    vec2( 0.000000, 1.000000)
);

vec3 Normals[] = vec3[6](
     vec3(-1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000),
     vec3( 0.0000,  0.0000, -1.0000),
     vec3( 1.0000,  0.0000, 0.00000),
     vec3( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.00000),
     vec3( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000),
     vec3( 0.0000,  1.0000, 0.0000)
);

out vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 camMatrix;


void main()
{
    // Outputs the positions/coordinates of all vertices
    gl_Position = camMatrix * vec4(Vertices[V_Indices], 1.0);
    // Assigns the colors from the Vertex Data to "color"

    // Assigns the texture coordinates from the Vertex Data to "texCoord"
    texCoord = Texcoords[T_Indices];
}
```

`

But in real conditions, it will not work to make arrays in the shader, moreover, the arrays will be of different lengths
The question is - is it possible to load an array of vertices into a VBO and then either get a VBO from a shader - as an array, or somehow read its elements by index
If not, then the question is - is it possible to make a dynamic array in the shader, and then pass vertexes to it? -
"uniform int ArrSize"
"uniform vec3 *arr = new vec3 [ArrSize];
[image]

[image]

Comment: "*I partially managed to implement rendering by individual indexes*" You really shouldn't do that. In most cases, it will be faster to just duplicate vertex data where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best fit for this task would be a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object):

```
layout(std430, binding=0) buffer VertexBuffer { vec3 Vertices[]; };
layout(std430, binding=1) buffer TexcoordBuffer { vec2 Texcoords[]; };
layout(std430, binding=2) buffer NormalBuffer { vec3 Normals[]; };
...
void main() {
    gl_Position = camMatrix * vec4(Vertices[V_Indices], 1.0);
    texCoord = Texcoords[T_Indices];
}
```

You'd bind the buffers with:

```
GLuint buffers[] = { vertexBuffer, texcoordBuffer, normalBuffer };
GLintptr offsets[] = { ... };
GLsizeiptr sizes[] = { ... };
glBindBuffersRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 3, buffers, offsets, sizes);
```

Although the layout of SSBOs is less flexible than VAOs, they do allow indexing very big buffers (usually as big as you can allocate).

However, **SSBOs were introduced in OpenGL 4.3,** and may only be available on earlier versions through an extension.

If you'd like it to work with earlier OpenGL versions, you may look at [Uniform Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) or [Buffer Textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture).